# THREE.js Turn THREE.planeGeometry to THREE.plane

Tags: javascript, three.js, linear-algebra, plane

I am trying to configure the position of a THREE.plane for localClipping, and Im finding it a little unintuitive.  I had a thought, is it possible to create some planeGeometry, manipulate it, and convert its position and orientation to the create a THREE.plane in its place?

This would be useful for configuring the position of a clipping planes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to set a `THREE.Plane` from a `Mesh` having a `PlaneGeometry`, and you want to take into consideration the mesh's `position` and `quaternion` (or `rotation`). In other words, you want the `THREE.Plane` to align with the planar `Mesh`.

The easiest way to do that is to use `plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint()`.

The normal is the normal to the plane mesh after rotation. The coplanar point is any point in the plane mesh; the `position` will do.

```
var plane = new THREE.Plane();
var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
var point = new THREE.Vector3();

normal.set( 0, 0, 1 ).applyQuaternion( planeMesh.quaternion );

point.copy( planeMesh.position );

plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint( normal, point );
```

three.js r.96

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how to scale the plane to size of my planeMesh? In other words, I want to clip an object only a little part of plane.

Comment: `THREE.Plane` is a mathematical construct that extends infinitely in 3D space. It has no size parameter. `THREE.PlaneHelper` has a size parameter for visualization.